# fosuserbundle override login action

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FSOUserBundle and I want to override loginAction, I used this method:

```
namespace PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController {

public function loginAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
{
    /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR))    {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = '';
    }

    if ($error) {
        // TODO: this is a potential security risk (see http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9523)
        $error = $error->getMessage();
    }
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME);

    $csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider')
        ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
        : null;


    return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
    ));
}
}
```

but when I try to show /login page I get a blank page, any idea ?!!.
forgive my bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed error by using:

```
namespace PjDZ\UserBundle\Controller;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController {
    public function loginAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request){
        $response = parent::loginAction($request);

        //do something else;

        return $response;
     }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks this fixed my problem.
Be sure that you dont use another Basecontroller. For the index for example, like me. You would get following exception:

```
 Compile Error: Cannot use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController because the name is already in use
```

I used:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as FOSController;

class SecurityController extends FOSController
```

Answer (score 8):

In Symfony version 3.3 and Fosuserbundle version 2.1.0, the above code will not work anymore until adding lines in **config.yml**:

```
services:
    fos_user.security.controller:
      class: MAIN\MAINFOSUserBundle\Controller\SecurityController

    fos_user.resetting.controller:
      class: MAIN\MAINFOSUserBundle\Controller\ResettingController

    fos_user.profile.controller:
      class: MAIN\MAINFOSUserBundle\Controller\ProfileController

    fos_user.change_password.controller:
      class: MAIN\MAINFOSUserBundle\Controller\ChangePasswordController
```

This is mainly because I keep friendsofsymfony up to date in **composer.json**

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"
```

Comment: services:
    fos_user.security.controller:
      class: MAIN\MAINFOSUserBundle\Controller\SecurityController        
      arguments: ['@?security.csrf.token_manager']
it works better 4me

Answer (score 4):

First off, is your bundle's parent set to FOSUserBundle?

```
// Acme\UserBundle\AcmeUserBundle.php

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
  public function getParent()
  {
     return 'FOSUserBundle';
  }
}
```

Secondly, have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Perfectly valid answer, clearing cache was something I'd neglected to do but solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone trying to do this with Symfony 4, you simply need to have a route in your routes.yaml with the same name as the one you want to overwrite and point it towards your own controller.

```
fos_user_security_login:
    path: /login
    controller: App\Controller\SecurityController::loginAction
```