# Symfony Change render login FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I use this in my navbar on my web site

```
{{ render(controller('FOSUserBundle:Security:login')) }}
```

And i put the login form in my navbar where my login work when i put the correct data into.. my problem come when the data is incorrect because the render redirect me on the login.html.twig page for say me the error message.
I think my problem is in this lines

```
     protected function renderLogin(array $data)
       {
      return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', $data);
    }
```

I try to change this, with the initial page or the directory of navbar but is not the good way..

How can i do??? I want the error message in the index and I do not want to redirect the login page..

Answer (score 0):

I personally had this problem; You can either override the login function of FOS, and handle the error when there's any, or do as i did, and create an ajax call for the login, and handle it yourself

Comment: if I ignore the login function like the second code I have put above my login is not working.. How can i do??

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194401/fosuserbundle-override-login-action