# Add extra field on login form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my **Symfony3** app. I have been requested to add an extra layer of security to the login page.

Let's say I get a custom key string (saved on the user computer) with JQuery.

I need to grab that key, and then send it along with the user credentials for verification to Symfony. That key will be stored in the database (I was thinking a new column in the user table) and when the user tries to log into the app, if there's no key or the key is different, it will give an error.

I read the documentation, and the closest topic to my needs is [this one](http://symfony.com/doc/master/security/custom_password_authenticator.html).

Except that I have to compare the token I send with the one in the database.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at Guard and http://symfony.com/doc/master/security/guard_authentication.html#building-a-login-form

Comment: Thanks for that linkt. However I don't need to create a token, and I will use that key only when the user tries to log into the web app. Using Guard will require to rewrite several things. Is there a faster way to check the token I get via JQuery with the one with the database?

Comment: hmm Well, may be I can get the key stored in the database and compare it to the key I get from JQuery, and if they match, show the login form. Is that something that can be done (get the key from the db)?

Comment: Sure it can be done but without any code or details I'm not even sure what you're really asking.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. Like have a key stored in the database, and then, when someone tries to login, do an "if" to compare the one in the database to another one that I will get via JQuery or Ajax: 



 {% if db_token == 'a4a6579' %} hello world {% endif %}

Comment: did you try to override security controller ? here is a sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194401/fosuserbundle-override-login-action